# getting data from three tables with conditions

Tags: sql, subquery

I have 3 Tables in SQL
Users
`UserID|UserName|password`
`1:John:abc123`
`2:Sara:asdfr`
AppRights
`apprightkey|description`
`removedata:Can Remove Data`
`adddata:Can Insert New Data`
`viewdata:Only Can View Data`
UserRights
`userid|rightkey`
`1:adddata`
`1:removedata`
`2:removedata`

Here is the Problem that I want to get the description from AppRights table by inserting user id but only those which are available in UserRights table.
I also tried like this but it is returning nothing in the result.
`select Decsription 
 from AppRights 
 where AppRigthKey = (select RrightKey from UserRights where userid=1);`

Comment: Try my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
select Decsription 
from AppRights 
where AppRigthKey = (select RrightKey from UserRights);
```

I think, you have some typo in your Queries. 
Try my answer:

```
DECLARE @Users TABLE(UserID INT, UserName VARCHAR(10),password VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @Users VALUES(1,'John','abc123')
INSERT INTO @Users VALUES(2,'Sara','asdfr')

DECLARE @AppRights TABLE(apprightkey VARCHAR(100),description VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @AppRights VALUES('removedata','Can Remove Data')
INSERT INTO @AppRights VALUES('adddata','Can Insert New Data')
INSERT INTO @AppRights VALUES('viewdata','Only Can View Data')

DECLARE @UserRights TABLE(userid INT,rightkey VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @UserRights VALUES(1,'adddata')
INSERT INTO @UserRights VALUES(1,'removedata')
INSERT INTO @UserRights VALUES(2,'removedata')

select description 
from @AppRights 
where apprightkey IN (select rightkey from @UserRights where userid=1);
```

Try the following for your tables:

```
select description 
from AppRights 
where apprightkey IN (select rightkey from UserRights where userid=1);
```

Comment: I am sorry for an inappropriate description of the question, Please can you take a look at the question again, now I asked in another dimension.

Comment: I can't believe that my hours' headache is finally solved, actually, there was a problem with my working DB column name.

Comment: Yeah, Everyone should face this problem at-least once.

Comment: But your Help is very helpful for me. Good to be here. Keep It up.

Answer (score 0):

This is valid syntax:

```
select Decsription from AppRights 
where AppRigthKey = (select RrightKey from UserRights);
```

But you do need to ensure only one value is returned by the subquery, one way to ensure this is:

```
select Decsription from AppRights 
where AppRigthKey = (select max(RrightKey) from UserRights);
```

Alternatively, using IN can be helpful as this allows the subquery to return multiple values.

```
select Decsription from AppRights 
where AppRigthKey IN (select RrightKey from UserRights);
```

However this could also case the query to display more rows as well.

Comment: yes by using this it is returning only one value
`select Decsription from AppRights where AppRigthKey =(select RrightKey from UserRights where UserID=1)`

Comment: Be on guard for possible bugs, a subquery of his nature (when evaluated against equals) **MUST** return one and only one row. If some futre ata model change is made *could* `select RrightKey from UserRights where UserID=1` return more then one row? if the answer is "maybe" then do something to ensure your code does not break.

Comment: I really understand but still can't find anything as result. As well I really appreciate your help. @Used_By_Already

Comment: *place a blindfold over your eyes.* Press a few buttons. What is on the screen right now? *THAT is what I can see (nothing I am blindfolded).* IF you want a more precise answer you have to prepare a more complete question which involves providing sample data and expected result.

Comment: EDIT THE QUESTION. Add a few rows of data from each table into the question do not try to describe your data through comments. Do not use images of data. Text formatted as tables is the best.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that your subquery should return ONE row

```
SELECT field1 from TABLE1 where field1 = (SELECT field2 from TABLE2)
```

or if it's returning more that one you can use IN statement

```
SELECT field1 from TABLE1 where field1 IN (SELECT field2 from TABLE2)
```

In your case it may be like

```
select Decsription from AppRights where AppRigthKey IN (select RrightKey from UserRights);
```

Comment: _Columns_, not fields.